# Elastic Beanstalk AWS ebextensions Windows ASP.net private bin files best practices

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Deploying a ASP.NET web app to Elastic Beanstalk. Trying to find the proper way to deploy the app from Visual Studio using the AWS extensions. I've read up on the AWS ebextensions config files but I've also seen something on SO that there's quirks with ebextension files and Windows deployments. What I want to do is deploy my web app which relies on many private .NET dlls that need to go in the web site's bin folder. Right now I reference them directly from the project itself and mark them as 'Content' and 'Copy If Newer' in VS. Wondering if the better alternative is to package up these bin files, upload them to S3 and use the ebextensions to get them installed as part of the deployment process for an EB app. I'm struggling with how to properly do the latter idea. Any ideas on best practices for this case?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The dependencies required for any application should be included in deployment package.

I'd suggest you to adapt best practices and get rid of the DLL's included in your project folder. You can create packages for your dependencies and reference them from any other project. [Take a look here.](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) This way you can prevent duplicate dll's in deployment package.

Comment: These private dlls I'm referring to are our companies own business logic, not third party ones to download via NuGet. You aren't suggesting we make a NuGet package out of our own assemblies are you?

Comment: Yes I am. You can create custom nuget packages with your dll's. There are bunch of tools to accomplish this. I use myget. http://www.myget.org/

Comment: Interesting idea. Then again I can already download a zip from S3 using the ebextensions as part of EB deployment to accomplish the same thing

Comment: Sort of, yes. But I don't see difference between including to your project and downloading from s3 while deploying. You asked for the best practice, This is best and scalable way as far as I know. If you are intended to keep your deployment packages light, I'd suggest you to take a look at continious integration practice.

Comment: Hi @stonedauwg if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.